# CGAL neighbor search not working as expected

Tags: c++, cgal

I am trying to find the closest neighbor in a point cloud to a given point. I have followed the documentation example in which the points are stored in a user vector and the Tree only contains indices. Since the results were not what I was expecting, I am also computing the closest neighbor by brute force. Ill explain my code:

I have a vector of points (coarsePoints) and I have a vector of indices (xC_vertices). The indices are the points in coarsePoints that can be marked as closest neighbor.

This is how I compute the closest point using a brute force algorithm

```
for (int i = 0; i < d_vertices.size(); ++i) {
        Real minDistance = std::numeric_limits<Real>::infinity();
        int vertexId = -1;
        const auto &dPoint = highResPoints[d_vertices[i]];
        const CPF::Point_3 pD{dPoint[0], dPoint[1], dPoint[2]};
        for (int j = 0; j < xC_vertices.size(); ++j) {
            const auto &xPoint = coarsePoints[xC_vertices[j]];
            const CPF::Point_3 pC{xPoint[0], xPoint[1], xPoint[2]};

            if (CGAL::squared_distance(pC, pD) < minDistance) {
                vertexId = j;
                minDistance = CGAL::squared_distance(pC, pD);
            }
        }
```

When using CGAL, I have the following (based on the documentation example):

```
class My_point_property_map
{
    const sofa::helper::vector<CPF::SofaTypes::Point> &points;
    const std::vector<CPF::SofaTypes::Tetra::value_type> &xC_vertices;

public:
    typedef CPF::Point_3 value_type;
    typedef value_type &reference;
    typedef std::size_t key_type;
    typedef boost::lvalue_property_map_tag category;

    My_point_property_map(const sofa::helper::vector<CPF::SofaTypes::Point> &pts,
                          const std::vector<CPF::SofaTypes::Tetra::value_type> &xC_vertices_)
        : points(pts)
        , xC_vertices(xC_vertices_)

    {
    }

    value_type operator[](key_type k) const
    {
        const CPF::SofaTypes::Point &sPoint = points[xC_vertices[k]];
        return CPF::Point_3{sPoint[0], sPoint[1], sPoint[2]};
    }

    friend value_type get(const My_point_property_map &ppmap, key_type i) { return ppmap[i]; }

};

using SearchTraitsBase = CGAL::Search_traits_3<CPF::K>;
using SearchTraits = CGAL::Search_traits_adapter<std::size_t, My_point_property_map, SearchTraitsBase>;
using NeighborSearch = CGAL::Orthogonal_k_neighbor_search<SearchTraits>;
using Tree = NeighborSearch::Tree;
using Splitter = typename Tree::Splitter;
using SearchDistance = typename NeighborSearch::Distance;

int searchNeighbor() {
    My_point_property_map ppmap(coarsePoints, xC_vertices);
    Tree searchTree(boost::counting_iterator<int>(0),
                    boost::counting_iterator<int>(xC_vertices.size()),
                    Splitter(),
                    SearchTraits(ppmap));

    SearchDistance trDistance(ppmap);

       for (int i = 0; i < d_vertices.size(); ++i) {

// This is actually following the brute force algorithm, so I have the brute force id and distance available
        NeighborSearch search(searchTree, CPF::Point_3{dPoint[0], dPoint[1], dPoint[2]}, 1, 0, true, trDistance);
        for (const auto &searchResult : search) {
            if (searchResult.first != vertexId) {
                spdlog::get("cpf")->info("Brute force id = {}", vertexId);
                spdlog::get("cpf")->info("CGAL id = {}", searchResult.first);
                spdlog::get("cpf")->info("Brute force distance = {}", minDistance);
                spdlog::get("cpf")->info("CGAL distance = {}", searchResult.second);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This return a los of vertices that are actually different:

```
[2020-04-17 18:10:31.988] [cpf] [info] Brute force id = 386
[2020-04-17 18:10:31.988] [cpf] [info] CGAL id = 84
[2020-04-17 18:10:31.988] [cpf] [info] Brute force distance = 0.0
[2020-04-17 18:10:31.988] [cpf] [info] CGAL distance = 0.041339367896971506
```

I am not sure if I am using incorrectly the NeighborSearch or what is happening. Any ideas what might be wrong?